# How to store contact with only API key without OAuth?

Tags: node.js, google-people-api

I want to save the email address who signup in my site in a pre-defined single Google account's contacts. Google people API works only via OAuth. Here the destination to store is fixed, so I guess authentication is not required. How to do that? Below curl request is not working for me. Even [Google's try API page](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/createContact) displays API key authentication but it is throwing error.

```
curl --request POST \
  'https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people:createContact?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"emailAddresses":[{"value":"john.doe@gmail.com","displayName":"John Doe"}]}' \
  --compressed

{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, API key cannot be used for POST and PUT methods, while it can be used for GET method. So how about using OAuth2 and service account?

Comment: I can't use OAuth2, because here the google account in which I want to store the contacts is you can consider site's owner account, he is not an end-user. In a nutshell, I want to have a parallel list of contacts in google account who do signup in site. For service account, I will check the feasibility and get back.

Comment: Hello Farhan, have you found any solutions for this ?